# Python - Checking the number of internal elements in a 3D string list

Tags: python, list

We are working on counting the number of elements in the 3D string list and using that number.

```
eleli = [[["ele", "ele", "ele", "ele", "ele"], ["ele", "ele", "ele"]], [["ele", "ele", "ele", "ele", "ele"], ["ele", "ele", "ele", "ele"]], [["ele", "ele", "ele", "ele"], ["ele", "ele", "ele", "ele", "ele"]], [["ele", "ele"]]]

print(len(eleli))

>>>4
```

Is there a simple way to count all string elements in a list?

Comment: Break this into smaller parts. First how do you count the number of elements in a 1D list? Now take that solution and count all the elements in a 2D list. Finally rinse and repeat for 3D.

Comment: If 3d is ensured, `sum(map(len, itertools.chain.from_iterable(eleli)))` can be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
print(sum(len(e) for seq in eleli for e in seq))
```

Comment: I've been doing python for a while now and I don't think I've ever seen multiple `for`s in a comprehension like this. Thanks for the example! I will have to remember this when I want to faltten a list.

Comment: This method is perfect because you simply need to get the value. thank you

Answer (score 3):

Try something like the following:

```
eleli = [[["ele", "ele", "ele", "ele", "ele"], ["ele", "ele", "ele"]], [["ele", "ele", "ele", "ele", "ele"], ["ele", "ele", "ele", "ele"]], [["ele", "ele", "ele", "ele"], ["ele", "ele", "ele", "ele", "ele"]], [["ele", "ele"]]]

# Find the length of all primitive elements within the inner lists.

total = 0

for i in eleli:
    for j in i:
        total +=len(j)


print(total)
```